# Trying to get html respons

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to get html response using PHP but always get something like this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds0Qy.png) [picture hidden from post due to binary characters]

```
<?php

$header_request = array (
    "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding: gzip",
    "accept-language: id-ID,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "cookie: csrf_cookie_name=9316014c9d7860019da66a78edfaf926; _data_pop=115-1_274-1; ci_session=607f0be4e56b8b08ee2398b892f115c9e660192e; _data_cpc=1-2_15-2_190-4",
    "referer: https://ptc4btc.com/",
    "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto C Plus) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.56 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
    );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://ptc4btc.com/dashboard",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header_request,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
  ));

$exec = curl_exec($ch);
echo($exec);

curl_close($exec);
```

Comment: That's a gzipped file. You need to decode it.

Comment: Why do you have `accept-encoding: gzip` in the headers if you want the plain text?

Comment: The argument to `curl_close()` should be `$ch`, not `$exec`.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were willing to accept gzip data with `accept-encoding: gzip` in the headers. So decode it:

```
echo gzdecode($exec);
```